# How can I declare one variable with assigned value that can use for all module in vba?

Tags: vba

My question is how my variable and assigned value can be use for all module, for example like:

this is declare global module:

```
sub global()
public A as integer 
A=3
end sub
```

this is first module(for sheet1):

```
sub first()
if Sheet1.Cells(1, "A") > 100 then 
Sheet3.Cells(A, "A") = Sheet1.Cells(1, "B").Value
A=A+1

eng sub
```

this is second module(for sheet2):

```
sub second()
if Sheet2.Cells(1, "A") > 100 then
Sheet3.Cells(A, "A") = Sheet2.Cells(1, "B").Value

A=A+1
end sub
```

*i had separate the modules file for every single sheet such as sheet1 with module1 and sheet2 with module2.

so I expect that when `A` sum inside the first or second module will return to global() A value.

[example of my contain file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcsS1.png)

Comment: you need to declare the variable outside of a sub, at the top of the module.

Comment: @horst i had tried but i cant be run.do you have those example? when i find from stackoberflow mostly just declare for public in one module.

Comment: If you declare `Public Dim MyVar As Integer` it at the top of `Module1`, outside of any `Sub` or `Function`, then you can access it from  *any* module as `Module1.MyVar`

Comment: @chronocidal do you have an example? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments to [Vityata's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49855924/9290986), and edits to the Question:

> **Module1**

```vb
Option Explicit
Public A as Long
'Long and Integer use the same amount of Memory in VBA,
' so there is no reason not to use Long

Sub getglobal()
    A=3
End Sub
```

> **Module2**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub first()
    If Sheet1.Cells(1, "A") > 100 Then
        Sheet3.Cells(A, "A") = Sheet1.Cells(1, "B").Value
    End If
    Module1.A=Module1.A+1
End Sub
```

> **Module3**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub second()
    If Sheet2.Cells(1, "A") > 100 Then
        Sheet3.Cells(A, "A") = Sheet2.Cells(1, "B").Value
    End If
    Module1.A=Module1.A+1
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that a confusion is that when OP says "first module" they really mean a *sheet module* rather than a general code module. There is a good chance that they don't understand the difference.

Comment: @Chronocidal it pop up run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error.

Comment: @step What do you *mean* by that -- are these general code modules that you explicitly inserted or are they the code windows for things like `Sheet1` that are automatically created for you? It is confusing the way that you use the phrase "first module(for sheet1)"

Comment: @JohnColeman i had added a photo, you can get what i mean from that.thanks!

Comment: @JohnColeman first module(for sheet1) because i separate the sub in modules 1 for sheet 1 if sub is use for sheet 1 and modules2 for sheet 2 if sub is use for sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is achieved with declaring the variable like this `Public A As Integer` outside a sub or a function, in a module.

```
Public A As Integer

Sub SetGlobal()
    A = 3
End Sub
```

And then somewhere else:

```
Sub first()
    A = A + 3
    MsgBox A
End Sub
```

In general, you cannot name a Sub `Global`, because it is a name, used by the `VBE`.

---

If you want to have a minumum value of the public variable, then you may consider creating a class, which has a condition in the `Get`-property. If the minimum value is `3`, then the class should look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_lA As Long    
Public Property Get A() As Long        
    A = m_lA
    If A < 3 Then A = 3    
End Property

Public Property Let A(ByVal lNewValue As Long)    
    m_lA = lNewValue    
End Property
```

And you can call it from the modules like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public myVar As New publicA    
Public Sub TestMe()        
    Debug.Print myVar.A
    myVar.A = myVar.A * 30
    Debug.Print myVar.A    
End Sub
```

Comment: sry the global() just a example, but when i declare like this ,my other module(another module sheet) can get the assigned value then after A=A+3 will return the value back to global and change the global value become A=6?

Comment: @step - I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: @step "ModuleName.PublicVariableName" - so, if your Module is called `Module1`, then in `Module2` you can type `Module1.A` to access variable the `A` from Module `Module1`: `Module1.A = Module1.A + 3`

Comment: @Chronocidal can you write as code type for me? thanks you very much!

Comment: @Chronocidal actually my question is i have 3 module file name as getglobal(),first(),second().  and my A is decleare in getglobal() such as    Public A As Integer, then in first() i set A value as 3 =>(A=3) and if else to add up the A value like A=A+1 then A will become 4 then i want the 4 return to the A value then when i go second() using A value it will become A=4 and not = 3.

Comment: and for second() lets if else to add up the A value (A=A+1) and  A value become 5(A=5) in last result.

Comment: @Step: `getglobal()`, `first()` and `second()` are [Subroutines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/language-reference-vba/articles/sub-statement), not [Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa733572(v=vs.60)).  You need to declare your variable *outside* them, as Vityata has demonstrated in his examples

Comment: @Chronocidal i am sorry, i still have no idea.do you have any simple way to deliver the information?

Comment: @Chronocidal actually i just want my A value can be share to any sub for adding the A value.

Comment: @Vityata do you have simple way to deliver the answer? beucase i have no idea with that. my expect is my A value can be share to any sub  with all the module (like few modules page in the modules file) and can be add up like can be A=A+1 in several of the modules and return the added value to the A.

Comment: @step - There are two options in my answer - the option 1 is exactly what you need. Below the horizontal line, there is an option to declare a public class variable, which makes sure that `A` never goes below `3`, when you refer to it. Having said this, simply write `Public A As Integer` somewhere in a module, outside `Sub` or `Function` and it would work (but without the default value).

Comment: @Vityata okay,i try it now.Thanks a lots!

Comment: @Vityata i have edited my question to more details.help me have a look.thanks you so much.

Comment: @Vityata my A value is using to push the rows to next line with no overwriting the pasted value. because i declare both side the some of data will be replaced by the copy.

Comment: @Chronocidal my A value is using to push the rows to next line with no overwriting the pasted value. because i declare both side the some of data will be replaced by the copy.